# How code connects with running services?

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-spark

Its a very lame question but I really want to know path followed in this.

I'm learning spark, So I have installed spark and written my first spark program in Eclipse. To run my program in eclipse, Spark or spark services should be running.

My question is to understand, When i run my java program from eclipse, then in machine how it Identifies or how it reaches to the spark running services in back-end ? I really want to know how it starts from Eclipse and ends up connecting Spark ...!

Comment: Please read about Spark's deploy modes. When you run in `local` mode, all components are running in the local JVM, including executors. Please read through this page: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

This information is provided when constructing the `SparkConf` object.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkConf.html#setMaster-java.lang.String-

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("My Spark App");
```

It refers to either a cluster URL or `local` (mostly used for development).